# Excluding specific URL from HTTPS redirect on NGINX vhost

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to exclude specific URL from HTTPS redirect (all traffic is redirected from HTTP to HTTPS so i want to have one URL accessible thru HTTP).

URL to exclude:

http://www.domain.com/index.php?route=extension/something/something

My VHOST domain.com.conf:

```
server{
listen      80;
listen      443 ssl;
server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
ssl         on;

if ( $scheme = "http" ) {
rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://$host/$1 permanent;
}
index index.php index.html;

root /var/www/domain.com;

    keepalive_timeout   60;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com.key;

location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri = 404;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
}

location /image/data {
        autoindex on;
    }

location /upload {
        autoindex on;
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
    }

location /admin {
        index index.php;
    }

location / {
        try_files $uri @opencart;
    }

location @opencart {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
    }

location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
location ~* \.(xml|csv|xls)$ {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
}

location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|\.php_ {
        deny all;
    }

location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

I googled everything and tried all tips from here without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try below code,

```
server {
   ...
   set $is_redirect "0";
   if ( $scheme = "http" ) {
      set $is_redirect "1";
   }
   if ($arg_route ~* "extension/something/something") {
      set $is_redirect "0";
   }
   if ($is_redirect) {
      rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://$host/$1 permanent;
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for great solution. I have another question: How to add rewrite for these situation to have also returned HTTP?                                  rewrite ^/googlebase.xml$ /index.php?route=feed/google_base last;

Comment: i think you want the rewrite during http processing, try, if ( $scheme = "http" ) { rewrite ^/googlebase.xml$ /index.php?route=feed/google_base last; } below the third if block.